# DateTimePicker is not working Properly

Tags: .net

Actually , I have 2 dateTimePicker in my form in c sharp dot net 2008.Both of them perform same event.But One of them is not working Properly until i use another one.Please Help me OUT!!!!

```
    private void dtpStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cmbDay.SelectedIndex == -1 || cmbLeaveName.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select Day and Leave Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            dtpStart.ValueChanged -= new EventHandler(dtpStart_ValueChanged);

        }
        if (dtpStart.Value > dtpEnd.Value)
        {
              MessageBox.Show("The End date of leave cannot be occur before date of leave ", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            dtpStart.Value = dtpEnd.Value;
        }
        getdays();
        check = validate();
        if (check == "Incorrect")
        {
            check = "Correct";
            return;
        }
        LoadDataGridView();

    }


   private void dtpEnd_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbDay.SelectedIndex == -1 || cmbLeaveName.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select Day and Leave Name","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            dtpEnd.ValueChanged -= new EventHandler(dtpEnd_ValueChanged);
            return;

        }
        if (dtpEnd.Value < dtpStart.Value)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The End date of leave cannot be occur before date of leave ", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            dtpEnd.Value = dtpStart.Value;

        }
        getdays();
        check = validate();
        if (check == "Incorrect")
        {
            check = "Correct";
            return;
        }
        LoadDataGridView();

    }



    private void getdays()
    {
        double ts = GetDateDifference();
        if (cmbDay.Text.ToString() == "Full Day")
        {
            txtLeaveApplied.Text = ts.ToString();
        }
        else if (cmbDay.Text.ToString() == "Half Day")
        {
            txtLeaveApplied.Text = ((float.Parse(ts.ToString())) / 2).ToString();
        }

    }
    private string validate()
    {
        string Name = cmbApplicantName.Text.ToString();
        string EMP_ID = GetEmpId(Name);
        DataTable dtvalidate = new DataTable();

        dtvalidate = LI.ValidateLeaveInfo(EMP_ID,
           DateTime.Parse(dtpStart.Value.ToShortDateString()),
           DateTime.Parse(dtpEnd.Value.ToShortDateString()));
        if (dtvalidate.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DataRow row in dtvalidate.Rows)
            {
                date.Append(row["Leave_Date"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Leave Already applied in following Date(s)" +
                Environment.NewLine + date, "Select valid date", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            check = "Incorrect";
            dgvLeaveApplication.Rows.Clear();

        }
        dtvalidate.Rows.Clear();
        dtvalidate.Dispose();
        return check;
    }


    private void LoadDataGridView()
    {

        double ts = GetDateDifference();
        dgvLeaveApplication.Rows.Clear();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dtpStart.Value.ToShortDateString());
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(ts.ToString()); i++)
        {
            dgvLeaveApplication.Rows.Add(dgvLeaveApplication.Rows.Count,
                dt.ToShortDateString(), cmbLeaveName.SelectedValue.ToString());

            dt = dt.AddDays(1);

        }
        dgvLeaveApplication.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of removing the handlers?

Comment: because when i change the month it automatically increase month one by one such as 03/03/2011 ... 04/03/2011  05/03/2011 .. That's why i used .

Answer (score 1):

Check AutoPostBack property for both components.

Comment: I need in windows application not in web application

Answer (score 1):

You have some very strange constructions in your code. E.g.,

```
check = validate();
if (check == "Incorrect")
{
    check = "Correct";
    return;
}
```

(Why not have Validate() return a bool? And why are you ignoring validation errors?)
My advise is to restructure, rename and change signatures of your methods so the code becomes readable. That will make it a lot easier for you to find mistakes.

Did you step through the code using the debugger? Did the event get raised for both pickers?

**EDIT**
You remove the handler but never add it. So after removing it you have to decide when to add it again. That won't happen by magic!

Comment: Actually, dtpstart get event raised but dtpend do not until and unless i start dtpstart.

Comment: What do you mean by "start dtpstart"?

Comment: I added to my answer. It looks like you do not re-attach the handler.